# How to modify value of a django model object automatically when model item "edit/change" page is opened?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-admin

How to modify a value of a django model  object automatically when model item "edit/change" page is opened/clicked and not saved is clicked.?
Basically I need this to keep track of read and unread data items. Just like keeping track of email message read/unread.
I know how to implement it when save button is clicked in django admin and I am currently doing it manually, but I want to automatically change a particular value just when change/edit link is clicked, so that I can keep track of newly created orders. 
As shown in the screenshots below I want the boolean value "read"[second image] to be changed automatically when "id 26" is clicked[first image]

[image: list view]

[image: glimpse of admin page]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is perhaps to override `render_change_form()` in your `OrderAdmin` class, and set the boolean value for `read` at the point the form is rendered.

For example:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
        if obj is not None:
            obj.read = True
            obj.save()
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, add=add, change=change, form_url=form_url, obj=obj)
```

Comment: Many many thanks.I am indebted to you. I knew there must be some way but it seems django docs was unable to help me. I genuinely thinks that Django Docs needs more appropriate documentation. Anyway I am forever grateful to you. @Will Keeling